# Splunk - Adding pagination

Tags: pagination, splunk

I have these logs -

```
2020-01-09 06:20:03,965 - INFO - field1=1 field2=1554 
field3=100 host=1

2020-01-09 06:25:03,965 - INFO - field1=2.43 field2=1999 
field3=188 host=2

2020-01-09 06:30:03,965 - INFO - field1=3.43 field2=2300 
field3=222 host 1

2020-01-09 06:30:03,965 - INFO - field1=4.43 field2=2200 
field3=201 host 3

2020-01-09 06:30:03,965 - INFO - field1=4.43 field2=2500 
field3=200 host 2
```

In splunk, I need to add a pagination table that would have "host" as 1st column and the corresponding ("field2"+"field3") as the 2nd column.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what you are tyring to accomplish, but something like the following may steer you on the right path

```
index = ... | eval col2 = field2+field3 | table host, col2
```

You may need `eval col2 = field2.field3`